# change expiration auth cookie dynamically .net core identity

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core 3.1 Web API app with .NET Core Identity.
In `Startup.cs` I have the following code:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
});
```

But for some users I have different value of expiration time.

Can I overwrite expiration time of auth cookie dynamically? And if yes, what's the best way to do it? Maybe there is an option in `SignInManager<...>` or `UserManager<...>` that allow to overwrite this value?

Answer (score 2):

The Cookies for Identity is AspNetCore.Identity.Application, and its ExpireTimeSpan is set by [HandleSignInAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f2e6e6ff334176540ef0b3291122e359c2106d1a/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L297).

You can use cookie's `OnSigningIn` event to dynamically set expire time for specific user :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt => {
    opt.Events.OnSigningIn = async (signinContext) => {

        // you can use the pricipal to query claims 
        var email = signinContext.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        if ("xxxx@hotmail.com".Equals(email))
        {
            // set the expiration time according to claims dynamically 
            signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(100);
            signinContext.CookieOptions.Expires = signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUniversalTime();
        }
        else
        {
            signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60);
            signinContext.CookieOptions.Expires = signinContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUniversalTime();
        }      

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:

```
await this._signInManager.SignInAsync(user, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60)
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the cookie expiration. It should still work, because the *authentication ticket* in the cookie is expired, but the cookie is still sent by the browser. Not sure it's really an issue, but it's annoying...